# Binary Search through Array of Strings - C

Tags: c, arrays, binary-search

So I am attempting to use a binary search to find a certain word within a dictionary of words in an array. Currently my function looks like this,

```
void binsearch(char letters[], char changeletters[], char **dictionary[], int numwords){

printf("start binsearch\n");
int max = numwords;
int min = 0;
int mid;
int spot;

while (min <= max){

printf("start while in search\n");

    mid = (min + max) / 2;
    spot = strcmp(**dictionary[mid],changeletters);
    printf("%d", spot);

    if (spot == 0){
        printf("word found\n");
        printf("A permutation of %s that is a valid word is %s", letters, changeletters);
    }
    else if (spot < 0){
        printf("word not found and word is lower\n");
        min=spot+1;
    }
    else{
        printf("word no found and word is higher\n");
        max=spot-1;
    }
 }

     if( max > min)
         printf("Sorry, no permutations of %s form a word", letters);
}
```

The random printfs are to check how far the program is getting. Currently it fails at the string compare and I am not sure why. Any Ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "it fails"?  Are you getting runtime errors, unexpected results, something else?

Comment: It crashes when it tries to do the strcmp and store that value into spot

Comment: Can you post your code that calls the function so we can see how your dictionary is defined?  It looks like its a pointer issue.

Comment: Maybe `**dictionary[mid]` is the cause? It has `char` type, while `strcmp()` accepts `char*`. Try removing one asterisk to get `*dictionary[mid]`.